# The tag Wiki help block is not correctly rendered

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The block that provide a help about tag Wikis is not correctly rendered. The screenshot shows how I see it on Firefox 4.

[image: Firefox screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed -- the body class wasn't getting set properly.